# Check if any part of one string matches any part of other string

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking for a method to check if any part of one string is in another string. Each string is placed in a separate column and is containing a set of random codes. Please see examples of these below.   [image]

The method should check if any of the codes in the Original Fault column is present in the Current Fault Column string. As seen in the example each code is created with a DI and 4 digits following. Each raw can contain a random number of those codes. Right now I'm able to check if the whole string from the Original Fault columns is present in the Current fault columns, but I need a solution that would be able to check each individual code from the Original Fault column string in the Current Fault column string. if there is at least one match it should return a yes in a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how we can get this by using DAX:

```
CheckIfTrue =  VAR SplitByCharacter = " " VAR Org = SELECTEDVALUE(code[Orginal Faults]) VAR CurrentF = SELECTEDVALUE(code[Current Faults] ) VAR Table0 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", Org),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, MAX(TokenCount,1) )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word])

VAR Table1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", CurrentF),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, MAX(TokenCount,1) )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word]) RETURN    COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(Table0, Table1))+0   // Org
```

[image]

Additional example:

```
ShowError = VAR SplitByCharacter = " " VAR Org = SELECTEDVALUE(code[Orginal Faults]) VAR CurrentF = SELECTEDVALUE(code[Current Faults] ) VAR Table0 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", Org),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, MAX(TokenCount,1) )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word])

VAR Table1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            ROW ( "Text", CurrentF),
            VAR TokenCount =
                PATHLENGTH ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ) )
            RETURN
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, MAX(TokenCount,1) )
        ),
        "Word", PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( [Text], SplitByCharacter, "|" ), [Value] )
    ),
    "Word",[Word]) RETURN    CONCATENATEX(INTERSECT(Table0, Table1),[Word],";")  // Org
```

[image]

Comment: That works miracles,  does the job spot on, big thanks for that.

Comment: Is there a way to actually return the repeating values?

Comment: it depends on what you mean by "return repeating values", can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: My apologies, return matching values would be more accurate in this case. Basically, is it possible to create additional column which would return matching values from the Current and Original fault columns? Taking, for example, your table from above, it would return D43 for row 2 and D99 for row 3.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check this additional example;